# Visual studio code is saying svg image import is typescript error 2307

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a React/Typescript component in which I import an svg (this is built with Webpack's HtmlWebpackInlineSVGPlugin).

```
import RN_Logo from '../../../public/images/RN_logo.svg';
```

which I use later on in my render function

```
<img src={RN_Logo} className="RN__Logo"/>
```

And it works fine, renders when I build and everything. However the file in VS Code is red, and that line importing it is red and when I hover that line it says

```
Cannot find module '../../../public/images/RN_logo.svg'. ts(2307)
```

which is irritating, since it works I can't help but think the error message and marking of the line is wrong and should be turned off - is there a way to do that, preferably one that allows VS code to understand about imported image assets?

Comment: I should note that to get svg import to work with typescript I have a custom.d.ts file with this in it: declare module "*.svg" {
    const content: any;
    export default content;
}

Answer (score 4):

Ok so my suspicion that the custom.d.ts file was involved somehow was correct. The custom.d.ts file allows typescript to understand how to compile these resources when included in the tsConfig.json, but Visual Studio Code for some reason does not know about the custom.d.ts file - in order to let VS Code know in the files I need to import svg files I need to include a reference path - like so:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../custom.d.ts" />
```

where the path points to the location of the custom.d.ts file.

however while this has fixed it for my case I have read a bunch of bug reports on similar issues over the last few days and not sure if it will fix any other person's experience of a similar problem, relevant resources

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2709
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10346

As an aside, I have to admit that I feel if typescript knows how to compile the module, VS Code should know how to find the module without further work. But it doesn't.

Comment: Seriously saved my bacon. Anyone having issues with this using mocha and ts-node, this solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Add the path to your definition file to the `include` compiler option in your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        include: ["path/to/definition/file"]
    }
}
```

> **include**
>
> Specifies an array of filenames or patterns to include in the program.
>   These filenames are resolved relative to the directory containing the
>   `tsconfig.json` file.
>
> `include` and `exclude` support wildcard characters to make glob patterns:
>
> - `*` matches zero or more characters (excluding directory separators)
> - `?` matches any one character (excluding directory separators)
> - `**/` matches any directory nested to any level
>
> If a glob pattern doesn’t include a file extension, then only files with supported extensions are included (e.g. `.ts`, `.tsx`, and `.d.ts` by default, with `.js` and `.jsx` if `allowJs` is set to true).

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/tsconfig#include

Comment: Please provide some external resource(book, authoritative website, documentation) that supports your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although you answered the question yourself I'd like to share my experience. Looks like my vscode decides to pick `declarations.d.ts` (using `expo` and `react-native-svg` which is most likely your case) and tsconfig.json `"extends": "expo/tsconfig.base"`). Maybe that behavior changed over version changes. Here is the file `declarations.d.ts` that worked for me (in project root next to `tsconfig.json`) again `expo` and `react-native-svg`:

```
declare module "*.svg" {
  import React from 'react';
  import { SvgProps } from "react-native-svg";
  const content: React.FC<SvgProps>;
  export default content;
}
```